# Assigning icon to new extension in Windows

Tags: windows, icons

Here is code I tried:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\DLI\DefaultIcon]
@="c:\\dli\\fav.ico"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\DLI\shell\open\command]
@="c:\\dli\\dli.exe +i %1"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.dls]
@="DLI"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.dls\DefaultIcon]
@="c:\\dli\\fav.ico"
```

I assigned new extension to my application. I wanted also assign icon to files with this extenstion, but it doesn't work. File still is being shown with unknown icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Export the keys for a known file type, then edit them carefully and import. See if this works.
2. Undo your registry edits and use [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) instead. Just go to `Edit / New File Extension` and fill in the details:

   [image: 1]
3. Ensure the .ICO format is correct, then try [rebuilding the icon cache](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think this site might help - http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/178915-file-extension-type-icon-change.html

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Link only answers are not looked upon favourably here.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Default Programs editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/). It has a nice UI to change the associations and icons.

Click on the Entry "Icon", select the extension you want and change the Icon:

[image]

Comment: This does not allow to create a new file extension.